# How do I upload a CSV with French accents & emojis to Google Sheets?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, gspread

I'd like to upload a CSV to Google Sheets so that I can download it as an XLSX.

I'm currently using the following code from gspread:

```
with open(target, 'r') as file_obj:
    content = file_obj.read()
    client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, data=content)
```

It works until I use a csv file with special characters (e.g. "È"), French accents, emojis, etc. Then I get the following error on line 2.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2304: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've also tried `with open(target, encoding='utf-8') as file_obj:`, but that gives a different error on the 3rd line instead of the first:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 944: Body ('’') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

I'm not sure where in my code I would insert `body.encode('utf-8')`.

Using python3 on windows 10, opening the file with Chrome if that matters, and coding with vscode.

Comment: What does the traceback look like in the second case?

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo! I think I just fixed it with this:

```
with open(target, encoding='latin-1', mode='r') as file_obj:
```

Inspired by: https://github.com/MayroseLab/MayroseLab/issues/9